Remap only Right Ctrl without Karabiner-Elements
I'm constantly using option+arrow to navigate to the next/previous word. I used Karabiner-Elements to remap Right Ctrl to Right Option on my external (windows-like) keyboard, and the life was great. Some time ago, Karabiner stopped working, and I didn't manage to fix it.
How can I remap Right Ctrl -> Right Option only on the external keyboard, without remapping Left Ctrl? The built-in MacOS settings only allow to remap Left Ctrl and Right Ctrl simultaneously.

Nevermind, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58981641/15072863 worked for me. Tried marking my question as a duplicate, but looks like it doesn't work between different sites.

It dosen't. There's nothing wrong with posting your own answer, based on  your experiences implementing that answer, appropriately referencing that one.  It helps people here find it, and increases the visibility of the SO answer just a little
